# Nice DPad controllers for fighting games on XBOX 360

Tags: xbox-360, controllers

So I want to be able to play fighting games on a 360, but the D-Pad on the standard controller is terrible. I don't really want to use an arcade stick either.

Are there any controllers for the Xbox 360 that are specifically designed for using the D-Pad to play fighting games?

Comment: Shopping recommendations are considered off-topic on this site, so I'm voting to close. Please [read the FAQ](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: They actually make a very specific controller just for this use case.  Its the [Silver Play&Charge Controller](http://www.amazon.com/Xbox-360-Silver-Controller-Play-Charge/dp/B0041HROGG/ref=sr_1_3?s=videogames&ie=UTF8&qid=1294847613&sr=1-3).  You can't buy it without the charger kit, but the D-Pad does adjust (by rotating it) from 360 standard to a classic D-Pad

Comment: @Mana I reworded it so it is not a shopping recommendation. IT IS RELATED TO GAMING, so please explain, HOW IS THIS OFF TOPIC? "Shopping recommendations are considered off-topic for the website. They are too specific, often localized, and are open to a lot of subjectivity." Well I hardly see this as too specific or localized, so can this please be reponed? @bwarner @Oak

Comment: There are discussions on meta for the justifications for why "X recommendations" are off-topic.  Please open or add to a post on meta if you'd like to discuss it.

Comment: Because of (1) danixd's edit removing the reference to price and (2) tzenes' edit changing "better for" to "especially designed for", I'm reopening the question. If anyone still feels strongly that it should be closed or that it shouldn't have been closed in its original form, please do so [in the appropriate discussion on the meta site](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1630/orthodox-rule-followers).

Comment: Also danixd for future reference you can't put multiple "@user" notations in a single comment - only the first user gets the notification. So Mana got notified on your comment but bwarner and I were not notified.

Comment: Oh interesting, thank you Oak. I am going to open a disucssion in the Meta because the question is exactly the same, just worded differently, yet somehow it becomes on topic. I know people are just sticking to the rules, but to me, Mana was being anal about the whole thing. (I use other SE forums and exactly the same thing happens there too)

Comment: @danixd: The first word in the last paragraph should be 'are', btw. I'd do it myself, but I thought you might rather...

Comment: @Ullallulloo lol thanks. I wouldn't have been mad if you had done it. I guess you saw my meta discussion :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MadCatz released, along with arcade sticks, a [FightPad](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001M22WMO). I haven't used it myself, but I've read good reviews.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like the best option before an arcade stick.

Answer (score 2):

There is new [Razer Onza](http://ap.razerzone.com/gaming-console-peripherals/razer-onza-te) pad in development which looks very promising. D-pad design is different from other controllers (they also call it "Precision D-Pad" whatever that means), but most importantly there are 2 extra programmable shoulder buttons and analog sticks with adjustable resistance (and hopefully less dead zone). Regular buttons should be different too with faster response (similar to mouse buttons). There is no in-depth reviews yet, but it is just about to start shipping.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should get the [Silver Play&Charge Controller](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0041HROGG).  It comes with a specially designed D-Pad that can be "rotated" dropping away the plastic in-between and making for a more classic D-Pad feel.

Comment: It seems this controller has bad reviews for fighting games. http://www.amazon.com/Xbox-360-Silver-Controller-Play-Charge/product-reviews/B0041HROGG/ref=cm_cr_pr_hist_1?ie=UTF8&showViewpoints=0&filterBy=addOneStar